# Problems with using fontawesome icons as background on <input>

Tags: html, css, icons, font-awesome

As title says, I want to have font-awesome icon as a background on my `<input>` element. For some reason it's not working. My code is:

HTML:

```
<input class="mod mod-inp inp-alr" placeholder="This is an alert"/>
```

CSS:

```
.mod-inp {
    position: relative;
}

.mod-inp:before {
    content: "\f000";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: inherit;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: input is empty HTML element you can't use before or after pseudo elements on input tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML elements like input and img are considered *empty*. There is no content in them, and therefore they cannot have `:before` or `:after` attributes as there's nothing to wrap.

What you may consider is using a `<label>` in your code, like this:

`<label class="mod-inp"><input type="text" /></label>`

and applying the icon to the label. That way, clicking on the label/icon will still give focus to the child input element.

Comment: Thanks, Works well now.